# NAT punchthrough failed

Tags: unity, networking, mobile

I finished my game while I was unaware of this error since it only shows up when I disable "WIFI" on my phone and testing it with `3G` and `4G`. Otherwise, when both devices are on my personal network (and I believe the same network in general) the game works perfectly fine.

Whenever two players connect via my own `MasterServer` I have setup on Amazon AWS services I get this error `Receiving NAT punchthrough attempt from target "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" failed` in the Unity console for both players. I am running both the Unity `MasterServer` and `Facilitator` on the server.

There are many question around the internet like this but not a single one with a answer. If this is really not easily fixable Unity should at least mention it's flaws where it provides the MasterServer. I would love to have an answer or at least some insight since now I have my own Linux server on Amazon I'd like to use it too. Currently it looks like my best alternative is using the multi-player options from Google Play Services.

This is the log I get from the server. Looks perfectly fine but it might help answering.

```
03-02-2015 02:28:31     INFO    New connection established to 24.XXX.XXX.X:62501
03-02-2015 02:28:31     INFO    Query request from 24.XXX.XXX.X:62501
03-02-2015 02:28:31     DEBUG   Version 2.0.0 connected
03-02-2015 02:28:31     INFO    Table Buckrider_Studio_FourInARow3D not found during query or row removal from 24.XXX.XXX.X:62501
03-02-2015 02:28:41     INFO    Connection with 24.XXX.XXX.X:62501 closed
03-02-2015 02:28:41     INFO    Removing rows for IP 24.XXX.XXX.X:62501
03-02-2015 02:28:41     INFO    24.132.7.159:62501 has diconnected
03-02-2015 02:28:41     INFO    New connection established to 24.XXX.XXX.X:61335 (166633197962428130)
03-02-2015 02:28:41     INFO    New connection established to 24.XXX.XXX.X:61336
03-02-2015 02:28:41     INFO    Update row request from 24.XXX.XXX.X:61336
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Version 2.0.0 connected
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Table Buckrider_Studio_FourInARow3D created.
03-02-2015 02:28:41     INFO    Sent row ID 0 in Buckrider_Studio_FourInARow3D to host at 24.XXX.XXX.X:61336
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Updating, inserting 4 at column 4
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Updating, inserting public at column 5
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Updating, inserting 6 at column 6
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Updating, inserting 7 at column 7
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Updating, inserting 8 at column 8
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Updating, injecting 24.XXX.XXX.X at column 9
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Updating, injecting 61336 at column 10
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Updating, inserting Welcome to Connect four 3D! at column 11
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Updating, inserting 166633197962428130 at column 12
03-02-2015 02:28:41     DEBUG   Internal port is 23466 IPs set as 192.XXX.XXX.X
03-02-2015 02:28:50     INFO    New connection established to 188.XXX.XXX.X:46374
03-02-2015 02:28:50     INFO    Query request from 188.XXX.XXX.X:46374
03-02-2015 02:28:50     DEBUG   Version 2.0.0 connected
03-02-2015 02:28:50     INFO    Fetching existing table Buckrider_Studio_FourInARow3D
03-02-2015 02:28:51     INFO    Connection with 188.XXX.XXX.X closed
03-02-2015 02:28:51     INFO    Removing rows for IP 188.XXX.XXX.X:46374
03-02-2015 02:28:51     INFO    188.XXX.XXX.X:46374 has diconnected
03-02-2015 02:28:51     INFO    New connection established to 188.XXX.XXX.X:46375 (300946669)
```

Comment: Get this all the time whenever I test my project across networks. No solution on the internet, and I'm just putting off dealing with it at the moment. This part of the master server just plain and simple does not work and Unity makes little mention of it.

Comment: @Ben Yes it is getting frustrating. What is your alternative? Besides the Play Services multi-player options i'm wondering if I could easily setup a dedicated server on amazon. I believe the problem is letting the two clients communicate directly with eachother but if I let the server do all the work things might be different. This would mean to build a separate server build and run it, currently just brainstorming about it.

Answer (score 1):

Nat punch-through is [not guaranteed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching#Overview) to work in all circumstances. ISPs can filter out these types of requests, and [phone networks are notorious for doing so](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm). [This](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileNetworking.html) is what unity says about networking on mobile devices, and [This](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-MasterServer.html) is where they talk about nat punchthrough (which you are right, they make it sound like 'maybe' it will work). I hate giving [bad news](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mobile-networking-over-3g.106752/), but from my little amount of research on this subject, it looks to me like a [nonstarter](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/receiving-nat-punchthrough-attempt-from-target-failed.291110/). As a last ditch effort, perhaps confirming that the ports are reachable is the best place to start troubleshooting, perhaps by using a tool like canyouseeme.org or similar. If the ports are accessible (but just don't work over phone networks), then unfortunately you might be out of luck.

Comment: So any alternatives for running it on my own server so I have all the control? Maybe completely dedicated? If I understand things right the punchthrough is only needed because I connect the two player directly. If I run a dedicated server this is not required.

Comment: That is correct. If you host your own server, and make it accessible to the web (namely port forwarding the ports used by the server), then the clients won't need to do nat punchthrough, they should be able to connect directly to the server without much trouble. In the unity asset store, they have a number of server softwares for sale (www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/network), or (if you are like me and) if you are more hands on, making your own is a lot of fun. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sounds like a nice project want to know much more about networking anyway. But first I want to get my game running so I am currently switching to the Google Play Services api for turn based integration.